# How to select Text in appium in android

Tags: automation, appium, appium-android, appium-desktop, appium-java

[image]

```
**Appium version:**
```

[image]

```
Xpath: 
/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.RelativeLayout/androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView/android.widget.RelativeLayout[5]/android.widget.RelativeLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.TextView
```

```
android.widget.TextView[@text='Test Group']"
```

**I am so Confuse I tried last 2 day to find solution for this my query.

> How to Select my text in appium?**

```
**I tried many thing but Unable to click....**
```

> 1. 

```
List results = driver.findElements(MobileBy.AndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView(" + "new UiSelector().text(\"Test Group\"))"));
((WebElement) results).click();

Result : Nothing
```

> 2. 

```
List<WebElement> SelectGroup = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[@resource-id='com.flipkart.android:id/product_list_product_item_layout']/android.widget.RelativeLayout[@index='1']")); 
((WebElement) SelectGroup).click();

Result : Nothing
```

I user those Dependency List:

```
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Please Help me on As per latest version of APPIUM I try to fixed that error on My Code I will process by learning in Automation testing.
I show many Solution but no one is working for me.
if you need more details please ask me I will give another details